# Problem with md5 and hash

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

```
<form action="inc/login/login.php" method="post" id="userLogon">
    <div class="field required">
        Username: <input type="text" name="regduser" tabindex="1" /><br />
        </div>
        <div class="field required">
        Password: <input type="password" name="regdpass" tabindex="2" /><br />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submitUser" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="ureviewdu"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="Student"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['regduser']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['regdpass'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE uname='$myusername' and upass='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("regduser");
session_register("regdpass"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

**DB Submission**
[image: img1]

When I click submit for entering joe joe for user and pass. How do I get php to recognize joe for pass is actually '55abd89cb7ab6742370f0ad912fef335' ? How do i get php to be able to decipher this?

Anyone?

Comment: If it is is hashed in the DB, just hash it before sending it to the select, and you should not be doing an escape function on it (on save or to check). And I would use sha1 or stronger.

Comment: And a hash digest is not a cipher text, so it's not meant to be 'deciphered'.

Comment: @barfoon root = 63a9f0ea7bb98050796b649e85481845

Comment: How do I implement SHA256 into this script????? Anyone?

Comment: SHA256 is supported in MySQL 5.5, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2 Otherwise you need to use the `hash()` function in PHP and pass the resulting hash digest string to your SQL statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE uname='$myusername' and upass=MD5('$mypassword')
```

However, I need to advise you to read the blog by fearless leader about [using salted passwords and stronger hashing functions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html).  Don't implement weak security.

---

If the password in the database is already salted, you need to combine the plaintext password with the same salt *before* hashing.  Ideally, each user has its own unique random salt, stored in the same row with the uname and upass.  Then you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE uname='$myusername' 
  AND upass=MD5(CONCAT(usalt, '$mypassword'))
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to do this in PHP (the hash and salt)?

Comment: Marginally.  If you're concerned about transmitting plaintext passwords between PHP and your RDBMS, then set up an ssh tunnel between your app server and db server.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the actual digest itself; create it before sending it. There's the risk of potentially forgetting to escape it, plus the issue of escaping changing the password the user may submit. Hashing it in PHP is straightforward and unrisky in a select statement, while doing it on the server is maybe only marginally faster (if at all). In addition to the issue you suggest. Of course, my assumption is `mysql_real_escape_string()` would change the password by adding slashes, something which I am not entirely sure about.

Comment: I don't use the mysql extension, I use parameterized queries for cases like this.  Then there's no risk of escaping incorrectly.

Comment: There is if someone doesn't know what they're doing and makes mistakes, which is my point: It's easier to get it right in PHP in that case. I just have my eye on those who are less experienced and don't know to read it that way, which would be many of SO's visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Hash the password on the way in as well:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name
    WHERE uname = '$myusername' and upass = MD5('$mypassword')";
```

By the way, if your system isn't in production yet, I strongly advise you look for a more secure hashing algorithm such as SHA256. Not much of a change is required, as long as you have the ability to flush your current password records:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name
    WHERE uname = '$myusername' and upass = SHA2('$mypassword', 256)";
```

Comment: @user Then you need to know how its salted, and what the salt is

Comment: @user, where are your salts stored? You should fetch that beforehand, or perhaps in the same query (depending on your setup with salts).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, without giving an opinion on what is more secure:

> When I click submit for entering joe joe for user and pass. How do I
>   get php to recognize joe for pass is actually
>   '55abd89cb7ab6742370f0ad912fef335' ? How do i get php to be able to
>   decipher this?

```
$mypassword = md5(stripslashes($mypassword));

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE uname='$myusername' and upass='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```